# Tomcat Java Server Application Does Not Recover From Multiple Dependant java.net.SocketTimeoutExceptions

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, jsp, timeout

I have a Java/JSP web application served up by Tomcat that makes web service calls out to a partner web service to retrieve data.  The technologies used in the partner service are unknown.  The partner web service has frequent extended outages where it returns a SocketTimeoutException:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

If the partner web service has a brief outage, then recovers quickly, my application handles everything nicely.

If the partner web service has an extended outage of over an hour, and my application has had hundreds of calls to the service that have all timed out, at some point my application reaches a state where it does not recover.  The partner service comes back, but my application calls to that service still result in the same exact SocketTimeoutException error.

If I start and stop Tomcat at that point then everything works fine after.

I am not using http keep-alives.  My code is anal about cleaning up all object instances regardless of whether exceptions occur or not.  It seems like the Tomcat Java process is "using up" some resource (sockets?), throwing away one with each error, until there are no more that can be used.  Has anyone seen this before, and is there a solution apparent?  I have done much searching on the matter and not found anyone with an identical problem.

Thanks in advance!
John

Comment: when your system gets into this wedged state, have you done a stack dump or heap dump?  these could potentially point to various resource exhaustion issues.  additionally, you should list the open sockets on the computer before bouncing tomcat.

Comment: netstat -ano does indeed show a lot of TCP sockets stuck in the TIME_WAIT state.  The PID for most of these is 0, which is the system idle process.  What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a situation in the past where I was running out of slots in the TCP/IP stacks for connections that were in the TCP_WAIT state there are some hard limits complied into the operating systems that you can bump up against. The way to find out what the limit is is to use a tool like netstat if you are running on windows server you can use some of the tools from sysinternals.

The solution to your problem might be a design pattern called Circuit Braker which is explained in the book called http://pragprog.com/book/mnee/release-it

With the circuit breaker pattern what happens is that your calls to the remote web service flow through the circuit breaker which will open the breaker when too many calls to the remote service fail, when the breaker is in the open state calls to the remote service will fail right away in the breaker code, usually you can program the breaker to retry and see if it will open again. Anyway the book has a better explanation than the brief one I just gave you.

https://bitbucket.org/asaikali/circuitbreaker/ has an open source sample implementation of the CircuitBreaker pattern.

Comment: netstat -ano does indeed show a lot of TCP sockets stuck in the TIME_WAIT state.  The PID for most of these is 0, which is the system idle process.  What does that mean?

Comment: I found some good information (and suggestions) here:  http://wiki.apache.org/HttpComponents/FrequentlyAskedConnectionManagementQuestions

The code change I implemented was 'urlConn.setRequestProperty( "Connection", "close" );'

After the next outage I will report back here whether that code change was the actual fix.

Comment: We have only had one major outage since this fix was pushed into production, but after 1 hour of outage our servers recovered nicely.  The fix looks good.